# Tag merge request osx -> mac-os-x

Tags: support, status-completed, tagging, tag-synonyms

Anyone able to take care of the merger of [osx](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx) and [mac-os-x](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac-os-x) and add a synonym from one to the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Done

```
updating post history, 16 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 15 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 14 rows affected
updating Documentation tag proposal commitments, 0 rows affected
updating DocTags, 0 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, new count: 130
tag remapping of [mac-os-x] and [osx] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym osx -> mac-os-x was approved!
```

Comment: What did you do `sudo tag-get update`? ;)